# making a instant messenger box with php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to create an instant messaging box for users on my site, badically if a user goes onto another users profile they can write in the chat box and send an instant message to the other user.

I'm having trouble getting the mysql to get the results and filter it so that if
user 1 messages user 2 then only user 1 and user 2 can see the conversation.

At the moment though only the logged in user or ".$_SESSION['user_id']." can see the conversation but i want both users to be able to see their conversation between each other.

the other problem is that if user 3 messages user 2 as well as user 1 then user 2 gets all of the conversations from user 1 and 3 but i only want one conversation between each user per box.

my database ptb_chats looks like this:

```
id  |   to_user_id  |  from_user_id   | date_added|   content  |

2            2               1         April 2011      hello
```

here's my php:

```
<?php
    $chat_set = get_chats();
while ($chat = mysql_fetch_array($chat_set)) { ?>
             <?php echo "<div class=\"chat_row\">".$chat['content']."</div>"; ?>
        <? } ?>
```

here's my mysql:

```
function get_chats() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_chats, ptb_profiles
                        WHERE ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_chats.from_user_id
                        AND ptb_chats.to_user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."
                        ORDER BY ptb_chats.date_added ASC";
            $chat_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($query, $connection);
            return $chat_set;
        }
```

please can someone show me what i need to do to get this to work? thanks

Comment: Step 1: Stop using the antiquated, highly dangerous `mysql_query` interface and switch to something safer like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) before you get yourself into serious trouble with [SQL escaping mistakes](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: well what you need to do is to select if the receiver is found in the from_user_id field and display the convo ofcourse limit it to only 1 to_user_id per box.